# 2 UIView.size.height don't work?

Tags: swift, uiview

There is 2 UIView control.

```
@IBOutlet weak var vw: UIView!;
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!;
```

I want to set height = 0.0;

Like this...

```
vw.frame.size.height = 0.0;
lbl.frame.size.height = 0.0;
```

And

I do this !

```
override func viewWillAppear( animated: Bool )
{
    vw.frame.size.height = 0.0;
    lbl.frame.size.height = 0.0;
}

override func viewDidAppear( animated: Bool )
{
    vw.frame.size.height = 0.0;
    lbl.frame.size.height = 0.0;
}
```

But It's don't work !!!

How can I solved the problem ?

Why don't work ? Is script ?

It's very different to MicroSoft Control.

Thanks in advance ^^;;;

Comment: Did you also set autolayout constraints on the sizes of these views in the storyboard?

Comment: ah....yes... Is relate ?

Comment: It's the _cause_. You cannot change the _frame_ of a view that is sized by autolayout. You must set its _constraints_.

Comment: oh my god. I can't think that's problem.  Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code isn't crashing because the vw object is nil. Then its probably a problem with auto layout.

You have them as @IBOutlets, are the views created in a storyboard?

If so, are you using auto layout? If you are, you need to set the constant of the constraint for their height. Create an outlet to the constraint and connect it in storyboard to it (the same way you did the views).

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewWillAppear( animated: Bool ) {
     vwHeightConstraint.constant = 0
}
```

Your constraints still exist, so even when you set the frame height, the auto layout constraint just sets it back to the height defined in the storyboard.

Comment: vw control create in storyboard.

Comment: Yes you're right. Auto layout Problem. Thank you ^^a